# single table inheritance, has_many relationships and sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, eager-loading, single-table-inheritance, self-join

I have STI and has_many relationships setup between employees and reports filed by them. The employee team is structured in the database using a single table inheritance as shown below.

```rb
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports
  #More code goes here. Scroll down for details
end

class Vicepresident < Employee
  has_many :managers
  has_many :members
end

class Manager < Employee
  has_many :members
  belongs_to :vicepresident
end

class Member < Employee
  belongs_to :manager
  belongs_to :vicepresident
end
```

I want to have a method that lists all reports filed by an employee and all employees reporting into the chain. So for example, (i) `vp = Vicepresident.first; vp.all_reports` lists all reports filed by vice president, managers reporting to him/her and all the team members reporting to the managers. (ii) `mgr = Manager.first; mgr.all_reports` lists all reports filed by a manager and all the employees reporting to the manager.

The way I implemented it is as follows

1. add a class method employee_categories that lists all **employee-types** reporting into. e.g. `['Manager', 'Member']`
2. Use the above list to generate a list of all **employees** reporting into. `e.g. Employee.where(:vicepresident_id => 3).where(:type => ['Manager', 'Member'])`
3. Eager load reports for the employee list from #2. `e.g. Employee.where(:vicepresident_id => 3).where(:type => ['Manager', 'Member']).include(:reports)`

Code for #1, #2 and #3 shown here --

```rb
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :reports

   def self.employee_categories
      self.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
      .reject{|a| a.active_record.superclass.name != "Employee"}
      .collect {|a| a.name.to_s.singularize.capitalize}
   end

   def team_members
      id = self.class.name.downcase + "_id"
      Employee.where(id => self.id).where(:type => self.class.employee_categories)
   end

   def all_reports
      reports = []

      self.team_members.include(:reports).each do |emp|
        reports << emp.reports
      end

      return reports.flatten.sort {|x,y| y.created_at <=> x.created_at}
   end
end
```

I want to delegate the sort functionality in all_reports to SQL instead of Ruby. How do I do that? Also, is there a simpler way to do all_reports using table joins instead of going to these lengths?

Answer (score 0):

For the sorting question you can [use a `default_scope` with an `:order` parameter](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping) to let the database do your sorting.